# WPF - Border around Radio Button and Content

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've been searching around and could not find an answer to what seems like an easy thing.

How can I create a border outline around a WPF RadioButton and its contents? (See picture below)

[image: Outlined radio buttons]

I tried to use `BorderBrush` and `BorderThickness` but that applies to the "button itself" (the circle), not the entire thing.

```
<Style x:Key="RadioStyle" TargetType="RadioButton">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="AliceBlue"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
</Style>
```

```
<RadioButton ...  Style="{StaticResource RadioStyle}">
    Radio1
</RadioButton>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either create a custom `ControlTemplate` for the `RadioButton` or explicitly wrap the entire `RadioButton` in a `Border`:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <RadioButton Content="..." />
</Border>
```

Comment: Is it easy to create a template deriving from the original template and just add the border to it, keeping all the rest untouched?